# Create alias that can interact with arguments

Tags: alias

My ultimate goal is to simplify routine task of compilation and run.

Now I've following commands

```
 1. g++ foo.cpp -o foo --std=c++11
 2. chmod foo +x #this may be overkill
 3. ./foo
```

So, my question if this can be done like

```
compile foo
```

with alias or something like that

---

I've tried

```
alias compile='g++ $1.cpp -o $1 --std=c++11'
```

with no luck

Comment: You should use *make*, this is its jobs

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for a `function` not an `alias`.
Example:

```
compile() {

    g++ $1.cpp -o $1 --std=c++11
    chmod +x $1
    ./$1

}
```

Voilà!

HTH, Cheers